# header must be terminated by a line break" eclipse manifest.mf

Tags: eclipse, manifest.mf

how to fix "header must be terminated by a line break" eclipse?

I know this is known bug but since I am using previous version of eclipse I wanted to know workaround for this compile error in my manifest.mf.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the manifest in a pastebin?

Comment: If you mean Eclipse bug [350756](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350756) that is a patch to let Eclipse fix a user's error not a bug in Eclipse.

Comment: com.pqr.xyz.core;resolution:=optional
Export-Package: com.pqr.xyz.gui.bla,
 com.pqr.xyz.gui.serizlize.editor, 
 com.pqr.xyz.gui.serizlize.editor.page

Comment: I am getting error on last line

Comment: @nitind : above lines are  separated by newline ..

Comment: But does the last line of the file also end with a newline?

Comment: @nitind: how to end last line with new line?Just press return key and save?

Comment: @nitind : I tried what I asked you above,its not working..I am stuck here.

Comment: @nitind: here is my problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=214302

Comment: @nitind : sorry for so many comments I posted here..I just right clicked on file and select format option an dit resolved my problem..I would really like to know what that option did..I am trying to find that out..Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

The last empty line in the MANIFEST.MF must be empty, so if you have a space for example this error will show.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a new line break after the Header.I don't know the details ,but it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but after deleting the targeted lines and rewriting the same it was done.